# Is my proof for this claim correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Prove that for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R} $ such that $x,y>0$ and that fulfill $x\cdot y=1$, the following holds:

$$x+y=2 \quad iff \quad x=y=1$$

Steps I took:

$$\frac { xy }{ x } =\frac { 1 }{ x } \Rightarrow y=\frac { 1 }{ x } $$

$$1+\frac { 1 }{ 1 } =2$$

Is this good enough? It feels like something is missing.

**Constructing my proof using input from answers below:**

Assume: $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y>0$ and $xy=1$

1) $x+y=2\Rightarrow x=y=1$

$y=2-x\Rightarrow x+2-x=2$; therefore, $2-x=1$

2) $x=y=1\Rightarrow x+y=2$

$x+(2-x)=2$

$x(2-x)=1\Rightarrow 2x-x^{ 2 }=1\Rightarrow x^2-2x+1=0$

$(x-1)^2=0\Rightarrow x=1$

$y=2-x\Rightarrow y=1$

Comment: You have shown that $x=1,y=1$ satisfies the equations. You have not shown that nothing else does. Using your approach, one can. Substituting, we get $x+\frac{1}{x}=2$. Show this equation forces $x=1$.  It is somewhat more pleasant to subsitute $y=2-x$ in the equation $xy=1$, no fractions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How do I go about proving that nothing else can?

Comment: How did the equation simplify to $(x-1)^2=0$ ? I feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: Oh!. I forgot about the $xy=1$ in the initial claim. No wonder I got so confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30558/discussion-between-cherry-developer-and-andre-nicolas).

Comment: I do not use chat. But I will delete my previous comments, so the system will not object. Then here or under my annswer, you can ask any further questions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approaches described in the answers already posted are the most natural ones. But the following may be of interest. By expanding, we can show that for any $x$ and $y$ we have
$$(x-y)^2+4xy=(x+y)^2.\tag{1}$$
If $xy=1$ and $x+y=2$, then substituting in (1) we get $(x-y)^2=0$, and therefore $x=y$. Now from $x+y=2$ we find that $x=y=1$.

So **if** our two given equations hold, **then** $x=y=1$. And it is easy to verify that $x=y=1$ does indeed satisfy the equations.

Comment: I will add the actual proof to my original post. Please let me know what to add/fix/delete. I just started proof writing about a week ago and it's proving to be very difficult. I can't seem to organize my thoughts in a way that proves these "trivial" things.

Comment: Can you please look over the proof I have written up underneath my original question?

Comment: What is (currently) written is, I am afraid, some distance from being satisfactory. You use too many symbols and too few words.  Let's first look at part 2). You are trying to show that if $x=y=1$ then $x+y=2$. This is completely trivial, it says that $1+1=2$. The other direction, the one you call 1), is the one where we have to write a little, and where the stuff you wrote under 2) is relevant. (to be continued)

Comment: (Cont) To show that $x+y=2$ implies, in the presence of $xy=1$, that $x=y=1$ do this. Suppose that $x+y=2$. Then $y=2-x$. Substituting for $y$ in the equation $xy=1$, we obtain $x(2-x)=1$. This simplifies to $x^2-2x+1$, or equivalently $(x-1)^2=0$. But $(x-1)^2=0$ if and only of $x-1=0$, or equivalently if and only if $x=1$. Finally, from $x=1$ and $x+y=2$, we conclude that $y=1$.

Comment: I understand that my proof writing skills leave much to be desired, but I'm completely new to this. I have never done proof writing before in my mathematical career. (At least not formal proofs.) It's difficult for me to distinguish between what is trivial and doesn't need to be proved vs. the things that needs to be proved. I also have trouble organizing my thoughts into a mathematical proof. I imagine that practice will make perfect.

Comment: It takes a while.  But as a start, it is important to keep the logic straight. If you want to prove that $x=y=1\implies x+y=2$, then you can suppose that $x=y=1$ and then all you need is to verify that $x+y=2$. For the other direction, you want to prove that if $x+y=2$, then $x=y=1$ is forced. This is where you need an argument somewhat like the one you gave in 2).

Answer (score 3):

For the non-trivial way, suppose $x+y=2$, then $y=2-x$ and hence $x.(2-x)=1$, so $x^2-2x+1=0$. Now you can proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

In order to prove bi-conditional statements, iff, we must show that "both" directions are true. That is, if we have the statement "$A$ iff $B$", then we must show that "if $A$, then $B$. AND if $B$, then $A$", only then could we conclude $A$ iff $B$.

So, we first suppose that we have found $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y > 0$ and $xy=1$. Then, we must show that (1) if $x +y =2 $, then $x=y=1$ AND (2) if $x=y=1$, then $x+y=2$.

Direction (2) is painfully obvious, but use the comments from seeker for (1). What you have done in your post is show that if $xy=1$, then one number must be the multiplicative inverse of the other. This is fine, and in fact, true. However, this does not help prove your statement.

Comment: I will add the actual proof to my original post. Please let me know what to add/fix/delete. Proof writing is proving to be very difficult. Even for such seemingly simple things.